# Devaputra-māra in Hinduism

Tags: gods

Devaputra-māra - the deva of the sensuous realm, who tried to prevent Gautama Buddha from attaining liberation from the cycle of rebirth on the night of the Buddha’s enlightenment.

who is the correspondent character in the Hindu mythology?

Comment: We have Kama Deva in Hinduism who arouses lust in minds.